# Trying to use custom fonts with DirectWrite

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directwrite

I am trying to load a font file from memory. The resource script defines the font like this:

```
ID_FONT CUSTOM_RC "res/Montserrat-Regular.ttf"
```

And then I try to load the font resource like this:

```
IDWriteFactory5* dwFactory = nullptr;
DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(IDWriteFactory5),
    reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&dwFactory));

HRSRC resourceInfo = FindResourceW(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(ID_FONT),
    L"CUSTOM_RC");

HGLOBAL resourceData = LoadResource(instance, resourceInfo);

LPVOID resource = LockResource(resourceData);

DWORD size = SizeofResource(instance, resourceInfo);

DWORD fonts = 0;
HANDLE font = AddFontMemResourceEx(resource, size, 0, &fonts);
```

Then I create the IDWriteTextFormat like this:

```
IDWriteTextFormat* format;
dwFactory->CreateTextFormat(L"Montserrat", nullptr, DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_REGULAR,
    DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL, DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL, 20.0f, L"en-us",
    &format);
```

I get no issues loading the resource, but when I try to use the font, it doesn't work. It just gives me a different font, which I think is Ariel.

I also tried loading the font like this:

```
IDWriteInMemoryFontFileLoader* loader = nullptr;
dwFactory->CreateInMemoryFontFileLoader(&loader);
dwFactory->RegisterFontFileLoader(loader);

IDWriteFontFile* fontFile = nullptr;
loader->CreateInMemoryFontFileReference(dwFactory, resource, size, nullptr,
    &fontFile);
```

But now I have a IDWriteFontFile and I'm not sure how I am supposed to make a IDWriteTextFormat from it, or if it even is the proper way to load the resource.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or where to go from here.

Comment: [Creating a custom font set using font data loaded into memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/custom-font-sets-win10#creating-a-custom-font-set-using-font-data-loaded-into-memory)

Comment: I got the last block of code from that page. I just don't know what to do with the IDWriteFontFile object after that. How can I use it when I call CreateTextFormat of CreateTextLayout?

Comment: *"I just don't know what to do with the IDWriteFontFile object after that."* - that's exactly what is explained at the linked page...

Answer (score 0):

For each font file in the local file system, create an IDWriteFontFile that refers to it via `CreateFontFileReference`. And then add the IDWriteFontFile object to the font set builder using the `AddFontFile method`.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Custom Font Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/custom-font-sets-win10)

Comment: How do I use an IDWriteFontFile when I create a text format or text layout? I can't seem to find any examples online of how to use the IDWriteFontFile object.

Comment: "how to use the IDWriteFontFile object." Add the IDWriteFontFile object to the font set builder using the `AddFontFile method`. After all of the files have been added to the font set builder, the custom font set can be created via `CreateFontSet method`. I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Custom Font Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/custom-font-sets-win10).

Comment: @IsaiahLateer Haven't heard from you for a while. Have you got any updates about this issue? Could you please check my answer?